# Does sql search work with SSMS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, redgate

I can't see the red gate sql search [plugin](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) in SSMS 2008 R2.  It is supposed to display in the toolbar, but it does not.  I saw a [version](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=13676) on redgate forums that is supposed to fix the issue, that did not work.  I tried a repair install.  Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me out of the box. I have SQL Search 1.1.6.1 running under SSMS 2008 R2 with SP1 (10.50.2500.0)

Comment: The plugin mysteriously started working for me again recently.  I cant explain why.  Perhaps I installed a service pack or other update and just forgot.